# What's in your python mode hook?

Tags: python, emacs

I'm starting to look at python, trying to bootstrap myself here.

What's in your python mode hook?

I have some experience with emacs, but I'm not familiar with python.

- what's the preferred python mode? I have emacs 23.2 on Windows.
- Is there a flymake-for-python? (how do I set it up?)
- does autopair work with python? (how)
- does auto-complete work with python?  (hints?)
- etc etc

Thanks for any tips you can offer.

Comment: It sounds like you want a tutorial, do you have a specific problem at all?

Comment: No, I have the tutorial on Python, if that's what you mean. What I want is tips for starting with python in emacs.

Comment: I don't get why this is being voted to be closed. I see tons of questions like this "WIX tips and Tricks" "best .NET open source libraries" and so on. I am asking for tips and tricks using emacs for python, and people don't like that question apparently. Hmph. And downvoted, like it's an impolite question to ask, or something. Very odd.

Comment: From the FAQ: *"What kind of questions should I not ask here? [...] questions where [...] every answer is equally valid"*. Those other are wither historical oddities or should go as well.

Comment: Note, however, that you have the making of several perfectly good questions in the text. *"Is there a flymake-for-python? (how do I set it up?)"* is a real question. As is *"does autopair work with python?"*. But not *"what's the preferred python mode?"* which is utterly subjective.

Comment: @dmckee - actually, about python mode, I think that's wrong. There have been several go-arounds, and some of them were buggy and didn't work well. I'm trying to skip all the history and learn the answer.  This is similar to the "What's the best library for doing ZIP archives in .NET?" or maybe rephrased "How can I read and write zip archives in .NET?"  There are multiple "right" answers to that question, and it seems to be an ok question to ask. for some reason this one is not. I don't see the difference.  Anyway not a big deal, thanks for your input.

Answer (score 2):

Re: autopair. Yes, it works. I have autopair.el version 0.3. The docs at the top of autopair.el have an extension that makes triple quotes work.

My setup:

```
(require 'autopair)
(autopair-global-mode) ;; enable autopair in all buffers 
(setq autopair-autowrap t) ;; attempt to wrap selection

;; this mode-hook is taken straight from the comments in autopair.el
(add-hook 'python-mode-hook
      #'(lambda ()
          (setq autopair-handle-action-fns
            (list #'autopair-default-handle-action
              #'autopair-python-triple-quote-action))))
```